# conditional aggragation in pySpark groupby

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Easy question from a newbie in pySpark:
I have a df and I would like make a conditional aggragation, returning the aggregation result if denominator is different than 0 otherwise 0.

My tentative produces an error:

```
groupBy=["K"]
exprs=[(sum("A")+(sum("B"))/sum("C") if sum("C")!=0 else 0 ]
grouped_df=new_df.groupby(*groupBy).agg(*exprs)
```

Any hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `when/otherwise` for if/else:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
new_df.groupby("K").agg(
    psf.when(psf.sum("C")==0, psf.lit(0)).otherwise((psf.sum("A") + psf.sum("B"))/psf.sum("C")).alias("sum")
)
```

But you can also do it this way:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
new_df.groupby("K").agg(
    ((psf.sum("A") + psf.sum("B"))/psf.sum("C")).alias("sum")
).na.fill({"sum": 0})
```

Comment: Thank you Marie. You are my Guardian Angel :-) I am a newbie in PySpark as you'll have already guessed and your help is very welcome

Comment: :) it's really no problem, we all have to start somewhere